# Sci Fi book about a man travelling through portals from one dimension to another through who ends up in a place where mind control is prevalent

Tags: story-identification, novel, parallel-universe, mind-control

I read a book in the late 80s about a man travelling from one dimension to another through portals that are "right around the corner". He ends up in a place where mind control is prevalent and people wear a number on their clothes based on their level of ability (like 1 through 10 or 12). He is woefully out of place and shielded by one of these people, but he is dominated by a child who gives him nightmares when his protector is asleep. This is all I can remember.

Comment: You've put "right around the corner" into quotes. Is this a specific phrase that was used in the book? Were they referred to as 'portals'?

Comment: This reminds me of a short story by Larry Niven: "For a Foggy Night" but it couldn't be, based on the description of numbers and levels of ability.

Comment: Possible dupe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129270/trying-to-identify-old-sf-novel-about-mind-control/129304#129304

Comment: Yeah, I think this is Mind Traders

Comment: The child given nightmares are a feature in Mind Traders, btw

Comment: Mind Traders sounds like it could be it. Did the detective traveled to Riga through a portal? I remember the portals were accessible by turning a certain way and entering, thus the "right around the corner" aspect of them.